# What are the permissions the Android app needs?

Tags: discussion, android-app

The Android app just prompted for an update and it shows that it needs a new permission to see phone call stuff. Why would that be necessary for this app?

What other permissions does the app require, and why?

Comment: Of interest: [Why do so many applications require permission to read the phone state and identity?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/605)

Comment: Note: [the mobile apps are no longer supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/335251).

Answer (score 107, accepted):

### Required Permission

1. **Modify or delete file contents of your USB storage**

   We use this to cache data onto your phone's external storage (normally an SD card) per Google's standards
2. **Full network access**

   This one's pretty obvious. We need to access the internet.
3. **Access your contacts**

   If you're running Android Marshmallow (6.0) or above, and you attempt to login or register via Google, we use Marshmallow's new permission flow to request access to your accounts. This is described as "Allow Stack Exchange to access your contacts?" in the pop-up. We use this to retrieve a list of Google accounts enabled on your device, so that we can log you in using the one of your choosing.

   There is a new Google Login SDK that will allow us to not require this permission (instead of you telling the SDK which Google account of the user you want to authorize, it takes care of letting the user decide that on their own [or defaulting to an account if there's only one enabled]) but it requires significant back-end modifications to work for us, if/when we switch over to it this permission will be removed.

   This permission was added in version 1.0.76, before this version users on Android Marshmallow were not able to login using their Google accounts at all.
4. <s>**Retrieve running apps**</s>

   We use this to check the installation status of Facebook on your phone, to provide that login option or hide it completely. We also use this to bring up a list of applications when you try to open a question or answer in the browser that doesn't include ourselves.

   This permission was removed in version 1.0.2.
5. <s>**Read phone status and identity**</s>

   As [AI E](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217345/why-are-phone-call-permissions-required-in-the-android-app#comment704330_217345) pointed out in the comments, this is a terrifyingly scary message for a very common requirement. Without this permission we can't access any unique identifier for your device which throws off both our internal analytics and those from our partners (Quantcast, same company used for analytics on the websites). Without this even more basic analytics are questionable.

   Using the phone status permission lets us look at number of unique installs without relying on Google's dashboard for it, it also lets us know if multiple people are using one device, be able to tell the session length for each user in that scenario, etc.

   This permission was removed in version 1.0.2.

We also use some more minor permissions which the Play Store actually hides from you unless you ask for them, they are:

1. **Read contents of your USB storage**

   Without this we can't read the cached data we write using the counterpart permission.
2. **Retrieve data from the Internet, view network connections**

   Without this we can't check if the phone is connected to the internet before trying to retrieve something, leading to a crash.
3. **Control vibration, prevent phone from sleeping**

   These are both required for our notifications and for Google's built-in push notification system.
4. **Find accounts on the device**

   This is to give you one-tap login when using your phone's Google account to login to Stack Exchange.

If you have any questions or concerns about any of these permissions, please let me know. I wouldn't want to use an app that was doing something weird with my phone either.

Comment: Minor 4., "Find accounts on the device", seems obsolete to me. One tap may be nice (*if* you use Google; I don't, can you share numbers?), but does it really justify this permission?

Comment: @Raphael I do :)

Comment: Yeah, again a badly named permission I guess.

Comment: What's up with the 'Read Google Play Services configuration' permission? Is that a by-product of the 'Access Accounts' permission?

Comment: @REJH "Read google service configuration" is the same permission as the "Find accounts on the device" one, it's just Google's verbose description of what that same permission does.

Comment: `prevent phone from sleeping` is really not cool for the battery. I am surprised this would be required for GCM. (also, if the app crashes when trying to reach the internet when it is not connected, there is a flaw in the conception. Post your stacktrace, I'm sure we can work this out.)

Comment: @Raphael I'm exclusively using Google OpenID for SE. The implementation that requires the permission is *much better* than the workaround they'd have to do otherwise.

Comment: @FEichinger What, you having to enter your ID manually? That's presumably what everybody else does, so I don't follow. Where I stand, protecting data of everybody outweighs a little comfort for some.

Comment: @Raphael the majority of logins using the application have been using Google login. In fact, it's a big negative in the minds of the Google Play's team if we don't use Google login and not having it reduces our chances of every getting the application featured.

Comment: "System tools: test access to protected storage". From the order you've listed them (and the fact that it's the only one not accounted for) I guess this is the "Read contents of your USB storage" you listed? But it doesn't sound the same at all. Can you explain?

Comment: For some clarification: 1) the *permission* to `prevent phone from sleeping` isn't eating battery. Wrong use of it is :) As for `find accounts`: it doesn't *access* the accounts, just lists up available account-handlers. While this doesn't give away any credentials, admittedly this might be a concern towards privacy (which services does the device owner use?). If it were for SE only: fine with me, I trust them enough for that. Unfortunately, I don't trust those 3rd parties for analytics & ads at all, which get access to that as well. So I'm with @Raphael here.