# Please don't require USB storage permission for the Android app or justify why you need it

Tags: bug, android-app, security, privacy

The Google Play webpage for the Stack Exchange Android app shows that it requires permission to modify or delete USB storage content.

[image: a screenshot of the Google Play webpage for Stack Exchange showing the modify SD card permission highlighted]

Translation:

> Modifying and deleting contents of USB storage

Could this permission be removed? Since you get access to your own subfolder under `Android/` for free, it seems rather unreasonable.

If not, please give good explanation **why** (including, why couldn't a specific feature be implemented **without** using that permission).

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217345/what-are-the-permissions-the-android-app-needs

Comment: Caching. *15 chars*

Comment: Don’t you get access to your own subfolder under `Android/` for free?

Comment: If I understand the Android developer documentation correctly, this permissions is not needed to access your own folder in 4.4, not needed at all before 4.1, but it is needed in 4.1-4.3 if the user checks the "protect USB storage" option.

Comment: After a closer look at the permission I actually think you have somewhat of a point, the permission seems to be not needed if you ignore users that check a specific developer option. But you're making your point in a really bad and not-constructive way.

Comment: Dude I don't do eastern European... translate the screenshot into the language of the platform in which you are requesting assistance.

Comment: @mattdlockyer Sorry, i can’t. Google does not respect the `Accept-Language` browseer header and instead guesses the language based on IP.

Comment: @kinokijuf wow that's a major block. Sorry.

Comment: @mattdlockyer I once had an IP that Google thought was in Germany. I don’t speak a word of German.

Answer (score 14):

As I stated in the permissions FAQ thread, this is so we can write a cache to your SD card.

As stated in the comments, you do get that for free, but only [starting in API level 19](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) meaning if we didn't have this permission and tried to write anything to a cache on anything below KitKat the application would crash.

Answer (score 5):

> Could this permission be removed?

Possibly, but they've chosen to use it for a reason apparently. According to [What are the permissions the Android app needs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217345/152515) it's kind of important.

> **Modify or delete file contents of your USB storage**
>
> We use this to cache data onto your phone's external storage (normally an SD card) per Google's standards

They're not going to wipe your SD card.

Comment: Don’t you get access to your own subfolder under `Android/` for free?

Comment: I'm not an Android developer, so I can't tell you. I just quoted the reason why they chose to have this permission.

Comment: hmmm it seems you answers why without actually knowing why...

Comment: It shouldn't *seem* that way, because I just now explicitly said it was that way. :P

Comment: @ŁukaszL. if we had to know why without guessing or quoting other sources, no one on MSO would answer except for SE employees.  I think this answers the question as asked.  Of course, it doesn't answer the follow up comment though.